# android.app.RemoteServiceException on google play console

Tags: google-play-console

I found this crash on google play console

android.app.RemoteServiceException:

```
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1894)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7156)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

I can't know how to resolve this error

can anyone help me?

Comment: I saw the same thing today, did you get any more info?

Answer (score 0):

This error mostly occurs when you've started a `foreground service` but couldn't push the required notification.

And this error also does not provide many pieces of information.

If you want to find out the problem then debug your application carefully.

Comment: How can the solution for this be found through debugging on a local device when it is a remote exception?